# Infinite numbers of decimals for a finite point in a line

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, decimal-expansion

Recently I started studying real analysis. In the beginning itself I was introduced to numbers which can't be represented as ratios of other natural numbers. But before studying them  I had doubts about numbers which can be represented as ratios. Why is that numbers such as $\frac{1}{3}$, which represents a finite point in a line, needs infinitely many decimal numbers to represent itself?

I know how by computation we can keep on adding more and more numbers after the decimal point but never find a number $n$ such that $3n=1$. But intuitively it feels wrong that to locate a  finite point in a number line you need to divide the space between $0.3$ and $0.4$ infinitely many times

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! That is because  *rational* numbers are not necessarily *decimal* numbers. The latter correspond to numbers which can be written as a fraction with denominator a power of $10$. Why should it be the case for all fractions?

Comment: You need to think in terms of different types of numbers and you cannot expect that every type of numbers will have the same properties. Take, for example, integers and rationals. You cannot expect reciprocal of integer to be an integer, but it's true for rational numbers and so forth. We have irrational numbers that cannot be expressed as a rational number but every irrational number is a definite point on a number line.

Comment: Well the case for 1/3 is simple. Suppose you had a magic tool which allowed you to cut any line segment into 10 equal parts. Then using this tool you can't cut a line segment into 3 equal parts. Think why it is so. The above statement is technically expressed by saying that $1/3$ has an infinite decimal representation.

Comment: A line divided in 10 equal parts can never be divided into 3 equal parts because 10 is not multiple of 3. Each time we add a decimel point we are actually dividing the remainder into 10 equal parts and take the closest approx. But since 10 is not a multiple of 3 we can keep on dividing but there will always be some remainder. Thanks @ParamanandSingh

Comment: The right reasoning is that $3$ does not divide any power power of $10$. If $3$ is replaced by $25$ or $32$ you can see that they do divide a power of $10 $ and hence the magic tool can be used to cut a line segment into $25$ or $32$ equal parts.

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, you should upvote all the useful answers and accept the answer that is most useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but a kind of hint:

First, do you know about different "bases", like base 2 and base 10 numbers?

If so, you might want to consider how to express the number we (in base 10) write as $1/3$ ... in base $3$.

Second, let me argue in the other direction.

Suppose I agree with you and say "all finite points between 0 and 1 (to make it concrete) should be representable by just a finite number of digits". (It's not at all clear what the first "finite" in that sentence means, by the way).

How many digits are enough? If you take, say, 2 digits, then you can only express the numbers $.00, .01, .01, \ldots, .99$. There are only a hundred of those, and if you drew a picture, you'd see lots of gaps between them, so the number "line" wouldn't really be a number line.

If you took 20 digits, you'd only get $10^20$ numbers...and there'd still be gaps between them. But you COULD write them down in order, just as I did for the 2-digit numbers above.

With a little more work, you could imagine making a table like this:

```
1   .0
2   .1
3   .2
4   .3
5   .4
6   .5
7   .6
8   .7
9   .8
10  .9
11  .00
12  .01
13  .02
...
```

and every finite-decimal representation would appear on the right hand side. (Some numbers, like 0, appear multiple times, in position 0 and position 11, but that's OK). Anyhow that'd be a complete list of all the numbers you want to allow.

Now I need one more idea:

If you have an increasing sequence of numbers, and it never gets greater than $1$, then it approaches some limiting number. For instance, the numbers

$$
1/2 - 1/2\\
1/2 - 1/3\\
1/2 - 1/4\\
1/2 - 1/5\\
$$
are all less than one, and they approach the number $1/2$ as a limit.

(The "all less than 1" avoids problems like the sequence $1, 2, 3, \ldots$, which does not approach any single number as a limit.)

OK. Let's look at the numbers
$$
1/10\\
1/10 + 1/100 \\
1/10 + 1/100 + 1/1000 \\
1/10 + 1/100 + 1/1000 + 1/10000 \\
\ldots
$$
They're all less than $1$; they're an increasing sequence...so they have to approach some single number. What's the decimal representation of that number?

Hint: the decimal representations of the numbers in the sequence are $0.1, 0.11, 0.111, 0.1111, \ldots$.

Comment: Do you mean to say that with a number system of different base we can represent 1/3 with finite number of decimal points?

Comment: @SiddharthPrakash In base $3$, the number $\frac13$ is written as $0.1$, yes. However, in that base, numbers such as $\frac12$, $\frac15$ and $\frac{1}{10}$ do not have finite representations.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is that numbers such as 1/3 which represents a finite point in a line needs infinitely many decimal numbers to represent itself ?

This is the *wrong* question to ask.

---

The question you should be asking is:

> Why should we expect a finite point to have a finite decimal representation?

And the answer is **we shouldn't**. Any point with a finite decimal representation can be written as $$\frac{m}{10^k}$$ for some value of $k$. There is no reason to expect **every** number to be written in that form, and $\frac13$ is one such point that cannot be written as "something divided by 10 to some power".

Comment: While I agree with the point you're trying to make, telling someone who's trying to develop an intuition about a new concept "You shouldn't ask that question!" seems like very bad pedagogy to me.

Comment: @JohnHughes I disagree. I think that a large part of learning mathematics is learning to stop expecting something to be true just because you *think* it should be true. My point isn't that the *particular* question OP is asking is false, it's that in general, questions of the type "Why is this thing I think should be true not true?" are wrong, and should instead be replaced with "Why should this thing I think is true even be true?"

Comment: @JohnHughes I agree it may sound a little rough, but in the end, it's the same argument you make when you say "let me argue in the other direction".

Comment: Perhaps the same argument (or at least a similar one), but rather different pedagogy. In what I said, I just presented a bunch of things that OP would probably, with the current level of understand/intuition, agree with, but which contradict OP's original question's underlying assumption. That leads OP to the state of thinking "How can these contradictory things both be true?" Saying "Don't ask that!" instead leads OP to think "Jeez, my math skills are so broken I can't even ask proper questions" or (less charitably) "Hunh! They must not know the answer...they're afraid of my questions."